# permission error when running npm install -g @angular/cli

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I am new to Angular and trying to get started with a project.

But when I run

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

I receive the following error:

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
```

Comment: Angular is trying to build into your global node_modules library, for which you have no permissions. Try running cmd or bash on administrator mode (write cmd on windows and right click > run as administrator) and try it with that. Otherwise, you have permission issues (company possibly) so contact your superior about it

Answer (score 2):

It's a common problem and there are some solutions for that. To use administrative privilege can temporary solves the problem, but you may face other difficulties. I found the solution at [Resolving EACCES permissions errors when installing packages globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)
 helpful.

Comment: All worked perfectly. I just prefered to save it to ~/.bashrc and then do source ~/.bashrc rather than do it on the profile file, but that's pretty much it.